# Range.Paste Runtime error ao colar dados da web

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Ola.
Estou extraindo alguns dados de uma tabela html de um ERP que devido a limitações me levam a isso.
Enfim, o problema consiste de, ao copiar a tabela e tentar cola-lo com range.paste ou pastespecial da erro.

O código completo:

```
Sub Coletar_Web()


    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim clip As DataObject


    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "URL"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        On Error GoTo Copy

        With .document
            .getElementById("nome_u").Value = "usuario"
            .getElementById("senha").Value = "senha"
            .getElementById("submit").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Debug.Print .LocationURL

Copy:

        With ie
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "URL"
            Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
            Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        End With

        Set ieTable = ie.document.getElementById("itens")
        If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
            Set clip = New DataObject
            clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
            clip.PutInClipboard
            Sheet1.Range("A10").Paste
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

O erro ocorre nesse bloco:

```
Set ieTable = ie.document.getElementById("itens")
            If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
                Set clip = New DataObject
                clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
                clip.PutInClipboard
                Sheet1.Range("A1").Paste
            End If
```

Mais especificamente no Sheet1.Range("A1").Paste, lembrando que já usei diversas variações de Paste e PasteSpecial para tentar executar essa tarefa.

Tentando simular essa tarefa manualmente para então reproduzi-lo em vba, o ideal seria usando a opção Matching Destination formating ao colar por VBA, mas também não consegui reproduzir isso de forma eficiente. Copiando e colando dados simples para chegar a essa opção, o ideal foi PasteSpecial xlValues, mas também retorna erro.

EDIT:

Continuando com essa saga, tentei gravar um macro colando os dados e obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
```

Porém o erro persiste, provavelmente não esta relacionado ao `.PasteSpecial`, mas sim como estou armazenando o dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema alterando o formato que estava colando. O código ficou assim:

```
Set ieTable = IE.document.getElementById("itens")
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
    clip.PutInClipboard
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
End If
```